# multiprocessing initargs - how it works under the hood?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

1. I've assumed that `multiprocessing.Pool` uses `pickle` to pass `initargs` to child processes.

However I find the following stange:

```
value = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1)
multiprocess.Pool(initializer=worker, initargs=(value, )) # Works
```

But this does not work:
`pickle.dumps(value)`
throwing:

```
RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

Why is that, and how multiprocessing `initargs` can bypass that, as it's using pickle as well?

2. As I understand, `multiprocessing.Value` is using shared memory behind the scenes, what is the difference between inheritance or passing it via initargs?  Specifically speaking on Windows, where the code does not fork, so a new instance of `multiprocessing.Value` is created.

Answer (score 1):

And if you had instead passed an instance of multiprocessing.Lock(), the error message would have been **RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance**. These things can be passed as arguments if you are creating an instance of `multiprocessing.Process`, which is in fact what is being used when you say *initializer=worker, initargs=(value,)*. The test being made is whether a process is currently being spawned, which is not the case when you already have an existing process pool and are now just submitting some work for it. But why this restriction?

Would it make sense for you to be able to pickle this shared memory to a file and then a week later trying to unpickle it and use it? Of course not! Python cannot know that you would not be doing anything so foolish as that and so it places great restrictions on how shared memory and locks can be pickled/unpickled, which is only for passing to other processes.

Comment: I see. Though, I find it odd that `SharedMemory` and `SharerableList` objects can be `pickled`, and multiprocessing.Value() can not. Because as I understand the underline implementation is the same (shared memory).

Comment: Is there a whether two `multiprocessing.Value()`, or `multiprocessing.SharedMemory()`, objects that exists in processes, points to the same memory? like the `id()` function

Comment: Well, I might have misstated the issue slightly. It could be what the `Lock` and `Value` instances have in common is that they are both *synchronized* objects.. Anyway, regardless of the motivation, I have looked at the code and that *is* the check that is being performed, i.e. it is making sure that a process is currently being spawned. And, by the way, it uses a special subclass of `Pickler`, `ForkingPickler`.